# Inner static classes in java

Tags: java

```
public interface Bsuper {

    abstract class A {
        abstract void test1();

        void test2() {
            System.out.print("test2 ");
        }
    }
}

// second file
public class Bsub extends Bsuper.A {

    void test1() {
        System.out.print("test1 ");
    }
}

// third file
public class Bsubmain {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Bsub sub1 = new Bsub();
        Bsuper.A obj = new Bsub();
        sub1.test1();
        sub1.test2();
        obj.test1();
        obj.test2();
    }
}
```

It produces the output as expected `test1` `test2` `test1` `test2`, but my question is in the Bsuper class, class A is static we all know that and now with the abstract keyword it becomes abstract class, but how is it possible to have both abstract and static applied to class at the same time.Is class A really static also or is there any other explanation for it.Please answer!!

Comment: I don't see why `A` is supposed to be static.

Comment: I read that except methods everything in an interface is static.

Comment: @jwg Inner classes defined inside an interface are by default `static`.

Comment: I think static classes and abstract are really orthogonal concepts, so I don't see any problems here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that a `static` `inner` class is using a different concept of *static*.

In this case it means that **the inner class does not have access to the outer class's instance variables**.

```
public class Test {
    long n = 0;

    static class A {
        // Not allowed.
        long x = n;
    }

    class B {
        // Allowed.
        long x = n;
    }

}
```

Making them `abstract` does not change anything.

```
    abstract static class C {
        // Not allowed.
        long x = n;
    }

    abstract class D {
        // Allowed.
        long x = n;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

> how is it possible to have both abstract and static applied to class at the same time.

It is perfectly valid to have a `static abstract` class. This is different from having a `static abstract` method, which doesn't make sense, as you can't override such methods, and you're also making it `abstract`. But with `static` class, you can of course `extend` it, no issues. Making it `abstract` just restricts you with creating an instance of it.

So, even this is valid:

```
class Main {
    static abstract class Demo { }
    class ConcreteDemo extends Demo { }
}
```

In which case, you can't instantiate `Demo`, and sure you can instantiate `ConcreteDemo`.